# what filter to choose in weka for an id that consist of numbers and alphabets

Tags: filter, types, weka

I'm using weka for image classification, and in my CSV file, there are two columns one is class which is a numeric type and the other one is the ID. however, my id consists of numbers and alphabets. what I have to do now is to change the type of ID, but to what?

Comment: What Weka package are you planning to use with that dataset?